# QLineEdit visible width Setting?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

How may I set the visible width of QLineEdit with *Qt 4.8.1* and up. Example would be to set the visible width to some pixel size or character width.  I wish to only use C++ not QML.

My thought is in the direction of this block:

```
QHBoxLayout *nameRow = new QHBoxLayout; 

QLineEdit   *firstNameText = new QLineEdit,
            *middleIntText = new QLineEdit,
            *lastNameText = new QLineEdit;
//Whatever method is needed here to edit visible width
//firstNameText->???
//middleIntText->???
//lastNameText->???

nameRow->addWidget(firstNameText);
nameRow->addWidget(middleIntText);
nameRow->addWidget(lastNameText);

layout->addLayout(nameRow);

QWidget window;
window.setLayout(layout);
window.show();
```

**Answer Update:** (*or see below*)

```
firstNameText->setMaximumWidth(100);
firstNameText->setFixedWidth(120);

middleIntText->setMaximumWidth(50);
middleIntText->setFixedWidth(60);

lastNameText->setMaximumWidth(100);
lastNameText->setFixedWidth(120);
```

Comment: Are you saying you want the content area to crop to a certain size regardless of the actual width of the widget? You still want to allow any data size and widget width but not content area width?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
firstNameText->setMaximumWidth(100);
firstNameText->setFixedWidth(120);
```

You can use thse two functions and they will adjust the width accordingly.